# To determine file owner, size and date/time modified based on last modify date

Tags: unix

I would like to determine the ownership, size and date/time modified of files from a number of disk systems.

Is there a way to search for these files and directories recursively as the only solution I know is using find's -mtime option and that only returns a list of file names/paths based on a specified date range. I will need the ownership, size and date/time modified as well.

I knew stat will give the detail info with some post-processing, but is there any other option to find these files efficiently with the information I need on each file, as I have to deal with a huge files/directories across many file systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU find, you can use the `-ls` option to have find print the results in a format similar to `ls -isl` or use the `-printf` option to select exactly the fields you want. Examples:

```
find . -type f -mtime -3 -ls

find . -type f -mtime -3 -printf 'owner=%u (uid %U) size=%s bytes modified=%t name=%p\n'
```

Comment: good point. The only reason I went the xargs route was on the chance that he did not have GNU find. In any event, he should be happy when he checks his reponses ;)

Comment: @Radix as long as we're doing portability notes, I'll add that POSIX find includes neither `-ls` nor `-print0` although both of them are also present in BSD and `-ls` is present in Solaris.

Comment: I spend most of my life on FreeBSD, so you can understand :)

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you very much as your answer do exactly do a magic for me!  I see that you have the %s, %t, %U, etc in your command, tried change it and it give me other things so it must have some reason behind it, may I know if this is relate to the stat? If the %U means for the Uid for example, what is the alphebet that represent others field in the stat?  My interest to know as for knowledge in future use.  Secondly, may I know if there's a way to change the size to a human readable format.  I knew that -H option can so this but how am I going to apply this in the command?  Thanks heaps.

Comment: @Grace There are a ton of %-escapes in find -printf. I don't know all of them. I looked a few of them up in the find man page to build a working example. You can find the rest of them there. I don't think the ls -lh style of size output is one of them though.

Comment: Hi ALan, may I know hoe to find the %?? options menas?  I tried find --hep or printf --help, seem not going to right place.

Comment: Thank you Alan.  You did a great help!

Answer (score 0):

The GNU version of find has -user (for owner), -size (for file size), -mtime (for modified time).

Don't these options give you exactly what you need?

Comment: The issue with using find exclusively is that it will only return the filename and OP needs owner, size, and last modified.

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks for the answer but as Radix say, I need 3 fields.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your OP for readability and clarity.

Based on what I believe you are asking, you can combine `find` with `ls` to give you what you are looking for:

```
find . -type f -mtime -3d -print0 | xargs -0 ls -la
```

The above command-line statement will identify all files less than three days since modified and pipe the output to the ls command with the -la switch to give you full file information, as you indicated you needed. You can fiddle around with the find portion of the statement to identify the actual file set, but the back portion will always give you the details on the files.

Comment: HI Radix, thanks for the command, your answer is an option for me too, but I did prefer to grep directly since it is dealling of tons for files/directories.  I need to execute within few minutes of less than half a day at least to get the result out.  Thank you!